# Unable to store numbers using vector

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<int> oper(int A, int B) {
    
    std::vector <int> arrayV;

    int addition = A + B;
        arrayV.push_back(addition);
    int mutiplication = A * B;
        arrayV.push_back(mutiplication);
    int subtraction;
        if(A >=B ){
            subtraction = A - B;   
        }
        else(B >A );{
            subtraction = B - A;
        }
        arrayV.push_back(subtraction);
    int division;
         if(A >=B ){
            division = A / B;   
        }
         else(B >A );{
            division = B / A;
        }
        arrayV.push_back(division);
}
```

//Can anyone letme know where did I go wrong with my code that it keeps telling me "egmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)", I want arrayV to be able to store numbers after +, *, -, /;

Comment: Can you post the whole code, and how you call the function because I haven't seen anything suspicious? Maybe I missed something. (I do spot that you forget to `return` the vector, but that didn't explain why there's a segmentation fault)

Comment: That's the entire section I've got cause I perform this block of code in this very vector function(); even if I add return arrayV(), I will get an error code "prog.cpp:33:5: error: expected unqualified-id before return return arrayV;"

Comment: @justANewbie Faiing to return a vector may well cause a segmentation fault. It has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Is `else(B >A );{` what you actually have in your code? That doesn't look right to me.

Comment: @Embeddeder Then you must have written `return arrayV;` in the wrong place.

Comment: Note that your `else`s  have the wrong syntax; your "conditions" aren't conditions but the entire code of the branches. Remove the "conditions" and their semicolons.

Comment: @molbdnilo you're right! thank you every one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I and others have pointed out in the comments, you forgot to `return arrayV;`. Also, your `else` has the wrong syntax

```cpp
std::vector<int> oper(int A, int B) {
    
    std::vector <int> arrayV;

    int addition = A + B;
    arrayV.push_back(addition);

    int mutiplication = A * B;
    arrayV.push_back(mutiplication);

    int subtraction;
    if(A >=B ){
        subtraction = A - B;   
    }
    else{
        subtraction = B - A;
    }
    arrayV.push_back(subtraction);
    int division;
    if(A >=B ){
        division = A / B;   
    }
    else{
        division = B / A;
    }
    arrayV.push_back(division);
    return arrayV;
}
```